# Storyboard issue: app runs but seems to point to something else.

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I have a problem: I can't figure out which storyboard my app is using and where I can edit that.

I have two storyboards with content.

iPad.storyboard
iPhone.storyboard

I have a single viewController class. Which while I can successfully programmatically alter stuff like background color. When I run that app it appears that I'm getting information from a mysterious third unseen storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose which storyboard to load selecting it in xCode - click on target as shown in the screenshot and choose which storyboard you want for iPhone and iPad in the Main Interface field (if your app support them both):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your info.plist has a `Main storyboard file base name` field - check it out

Comment: I have a file called infoPlist.strings - but its blank other than a comment at the top.

/* Localized versions of Info.plist keys */

Comment: It's not that file. You should have a PROJECTNAME-info.plist file.

Comment: ah thanks. Can I delete the default ones that are in there safely?

Comment: As long as you supply a valid alternative of Storyboard names that are in your bundle.